# How to Set ESS user can add kpi, view kpi on performance?

Tags: php, ess, orangehrm

I tried to find the code that limit the role of ESS user in order to set the permission to ESS user. I want to allow them full access on performance page. if anyone know this problem can all of you share to me.:(

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what Version of OrangeHRM you are using but I tried with 3.3.2 and it looks a quite different to your picture so i'm guessing the code is going to differ too. Nevertheless, a good place to start is in `orangehrm/symfony/plugins/orangehrmPerformancePlugin/modules/Perfomance/actions` here you might find `searchReviewsAction.class.php` or something similar to the last part of the url for the page.

The closest code example I found in my orange was for saveing KPI which I see in your picture you can do too. So in `saveKpiAction.class.php`There is a function:

```
protected function _checkAuthentication($request = null) {
        $user = $this->getUser()->getAttribute('user');
        if (!($user->isAdmin())) {
            $this->forward(sfConfig::get('sf_secure_module'),       
            sfConfig::get('sf_secure_action'));
        }
     }
```

You can do some messing around here, disaballing these checks that pop up in the Performace plugin usually just one for each things like add KPI, copy KPI, this is really ghetto modding though, if you know symfony well i`m there are neater ways to add what rights an ess has.